# Freeing memory allocated in 2D structure

Tags: c, free

Hi I have following code where I am allocating a memory in 100by 250 array of structure. after using this i want to free the memory and I am not able to find a way.

```
/*trial programe for storing sample data for each beam of each ping*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
typedef struct{ // in this structure we will define the pointers. so just data type and variable.
    int count;
    float *samples;
    float *deTVG_BS;
} card;

main()
{
    //float a,*p;
    int i,j,k,l,m,variable;
    l=100;
    m=250;
    variable=10;
    card acard[l][m]; 
    //printf("size of acard before memory allocation is %d\n",sizeof(acard));


    /* now we will alocote memory for all the pointers we have defined in structure.
     * The memory size can be different for each pointer. 
     * In our case memory size will depends on number of samples for each beam.
     *   * */

    for(i=0;i<l;i++) // i is number of profiles
        {
            for (j=0;j<m;j++) // j is number of beam
                {
                    acard[i][j].count=variable; //from 1 to 400;
                    acard[i][j].samples=(float*)calloc(acard[i][j].count,sizeof(float));
                    acard[i][j].deTVG_BS=(float*)calloc(acard[i][j].count,sizeof(float));

                    for(k=0;k<acard[i][j].count;k++)
                        {
                            acard[i][j].samples[k]=k*1.0;// in reality will be different values
                            acard[i][j].deTVG_BS[k]=k*100.0; // in reality will be different values
                        }
                }
                printf("allocated memeory for profile %d\n",i);
        }

    for(i=0;i<l;i++) // i is number of profiles
        {
            for (j=0;j<m;j++) 
            {
                void free(acard[i][j].samples);
                void free(acard[i][j].deTVG_BS);

            }
        }

    void free(acard);
}
```

I am not sure if i should run the last for loop or just free(acard) is good enough?

Thank you so much in advance.
Anand

Answer (score 0):

Where ever you have called calloc and stored the return value, you need to call free on that value when you're finished with it.  Generally just free things in the reverse order that you allocated them will save you a lot of headaches.

For this it looks like you need to iterate over and do 2 frees on each acard[i][j] like you currently are.

you do not need to call free on acard however as this is a stack variable (actually I'd expect that to assert/crash trying to free something you haven't allocated with malloc/calloc/etc..)